# Replace UIViewController in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Situation:
I have an app with a TabBarController.

One of the tabs needs a correct login to a web service to function properly.
When the Tab is selected, I check if login was successful, if not, I want to show a login interface WITHIN that tab.

So far, by using a segue, I managed to show a modal UIViewController with a login interface, but it hides the Tab Bar, prohibiting the user to use the rest of the app.

I could solve this by just showing a UIAlertView, but I sincerely dislike that option.

So, given a **myTabRegularViewController** and a **myTabLoginViewController**, what is the best approach here. And, does it matter what would be the first ViewController to load?

EDIT:

my preferred logic would be as follows. In **myTabRegularViewController** I have this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if ([userDefaults objectForKey:@"loginSuccess"]){
       .....


    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not Logged In");
        //load myTabLoginViewController

    }
}
```

Comment: can't you resize your login view controller?

Comment: would that help in showing the Tabs?

Answer (score 0):

Create an object that implements the `UITabBarControllerDelegate` protocol and implement the `tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:` method.

Obviously you will want a different test than what I have, but here's a quick sample to show the idea.  (I created two tabs, one with a basic view controller and one with a navigation controller.)

```
- (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    if ([viewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
        UIViewController *login = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"login_controller"];
        [(UINavigationController *)viewController pushViewController:login animated:NO];
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Not sure how this works. When/how is the tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController: supposed to be triggered?

Comment: If you set the object that implements it as the delegate of your tab bar controller, it's triggered when someone attempts to select a tab.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution was the easiest with segues. In order to not hide the TabBar, I had to embed my myTabRegularViewController in a NavigationController.